# how to open binary data like pdf in database in windows adobe reader?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I save my document (PDF, Word, Image, or Excel file) in a table with Varbinary field in sql.

I want read them and send the data and then show with the corresponding software of Windows like Windows photo viewer or Adobe Reader.

It is on a web page, but I want to open with programs in computer not under control of asp.net. is it possible??

Comment: Is this on a web page?

Comment: yes,and want open them with programs on computer no one of controls in asp.net

Comment: Well then you need to write some control to retrieve the bytes from the database and write them to a response with an appropriate MIME type. Since you've mentioned controls, I'll assume you're in Web Forms. That means you need to write a handler. A generic handler (.ashx) is pretty easy to implement. Try doing a web search for "generic handler database file c#" and I think you'll find some helpful tutorials.

Comment: This should really be broken up into several separate questions – and those separate questions *definitely* already exist. A possible set of distinct questions: read `varbinary` data from SQL (Server?) in an ASP.NET (WebForms) app; generate a web response with a PDF content type; generate a web response with an explicit 'inline' content disposition property.

Answer (score 0):

You want to read the data into a byte array and write it to the browser. It will be something like this:

```
void WriteToBrowser(byte[] theData)
{
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf"; // or whatever is right for your data
    Response.OutputStream.Write(theData, 0, theData.Length);
    Response.End();
}
```